# mockgen command returns Slice not declared by package unsafe

Tags: go, mocking

I run mockgen command to generate mocks for a file

command:

```
mockgen --build_flags=--mod=mod -source pkg/database/db-conn.go -destination pkg/database/mocks/database.go -package database
```

my go file:

It consist of a DB interface which is having all the methods definations
and then a struct which has dbClient.
i am creating connection with mongo i initialize the struct and have DB object
which is then implemented later on

```
type DB interface {
    GetClient() *mongo.Client
    GetTenantDetails(tenantID string) (api.Tenant, error)
    }

type Database struct {
    dbClient *mongo.Client
}

func CreateMongoConnection(username, password, host string) (DB, error) {
    connectionURI := fmt.Sprintf(connectionStringTemplate, username, password, host)
    clientOptions := options.Client().ApplyURI(connectionURI)

    client, err := mongo.Connect(context.Background(), clientOptions)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("", "[MONGO-CREATE] host: %s, error: %v", host, err)
        return nil, err
    }

    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), connectTimeout*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    // Force a connection to verify our connection string
    err = client.Ping(ctx, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("", "[MONGO-PING] host: %s, error: %v", host, err)
        return nil, err
    }

    return &Database{dbClient: client}, nil
}

func (db *Database) GetClient() *mongo.Client {
    return db.dbClient
}

func (db *Database) GetTenantDetails(tenantID string) (api.Tenant, error) {
    mongoCollection := db.GetClient().Database(common.CommonDB).Collection(common.TenantCollection)

    var tenant api.Tenant
    filterOptions := FilterOptions{
        bson.D{
            {"tenantid", tenantID}},
        nil}

    dbErr := mongoCollection.FindOne(context.TODO(), filterOptions.Filter).Decode(&tenant)
    return tenant, dbErr
}
```

i get error which mainly consist of below error

```
/usr/local/go/src/internal/abi/unsafestring_go120.go:17:16: Slice not declared by package unsafe
/usr/local/go/src/internal/abi/abi.go:91:24: invalid operation: shift count (i % 8) (value of type int) must be unsigned integer
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/internal/atomic/types.go:518:16: expected ']', found any
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/stubs.go:229:24: expected 'IDENT', found '('
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace.go:1153:31: missing ',' in argument list
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/trace.go:1153:39: expected ';', found '{'
/usr/local/go/src/runtime/alg.go:294:18: undeclared name: any
```

and in the end i get

```
/root/go/pkg/mod/github.com/oapi-codegen/runtime@v1.0.0/styleparam.go:193:14: invalid operation: tt.Interface() (value with invalid type) is not an interface
/root/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.13.0/x/bsonx/bsoncore/value.go:889:19: DecodeRuneInString not declared by package utf8
/root/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.13.0/bson/bsonrw/value_writer.go:96:20: MaxInt32 not declared by package math
/root/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.13.0/bson/bsoncodec/default_value_encoders.go:32:7: cannot use (func() interface{} literal) (value of type func() interface{}) as func()
 invalid type value in struct literal
/root/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.13.0/bson/bsoncodec/uint_codec.go:64:18: MaxInt32 not declared by package math
/root/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.13.0/bson/bsoncodec/struct_codec.go:478:23: sc.cache.Load undefined (type sync.Map has no field or method Load)
/root/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.13.0/bson/bsoncodec/default_value_decoders.go:313:17: MinInt8 not declared by 
/root/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.13.0/bson/bsoncodec/codec_cache.go:85:10: c.cache.Range undefined (type sync.Map has no field or method Range)
/root/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.13.0/internal/csot/csot.go:33:9: cannot compare ctx.Value((timeoutKey literal)) != nil (operator != not defined for invalid type)
/root/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.13.0/x/mongo/driver/topology/rtt_monitor.go:238:28: MaxInt64 not declared by package math
/usr/local/go/src/os/exec/exec.go:475:26: undeclared name: any
/root/go/pkg/mod/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver@v1.13.0/mongo/background_context.go:26:9: cannot use &(backgroundContext literal) (value of type *backgroundContext) as context.Context val
ue in return statement: wrong type for method Value
2023/12/08 01:33:06 Loading input failed: loading package failed
```

not sure what actually is causing this issue.
I tried using all option available on the different posts but none of them work.

Comment: You have a broken Go installation. Make sure your toolchain is up to date and correctly installed.

Comment: Thanks i guess it was wrong. working now